# What is $Q_f(x,y)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem says
Let $f\in F[x]$. show $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ is a polynomial $Q_f(x,y)$ in x and y.
But I don't know what is $Q_f(x,y)$.

Comment: That's just the name they're giving to the object you are constructing.

Comment: Indeed, you might look at the text as a definition of $Q_f(x,y)$.

Comment: $Q_f$ is the polynomial $(f(y)-f(x))/(y-x)$. But why is it a polynomial? Because  $y-x$ divides $f(y)-f(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably $\Bbb F$ is a field.   In $\Bbb F[x][y]$ we have *the factor theorem*, which says that whenever $p(a)=0$, we have $(x-a)\mid p(x)$.

Now if we take $p(y)=f(y)-f(x)$, then $p(x)=0$.  Hence $(y-x)\mid p(y)$.

---

Actually we only need to start with a commutative ring.